# How does windows 8 task manager startup work?

Tags: windows, boot

To be more specific, if I disable a program via the task manager menu that is set to run when windows starts up, what actually happens here?

Does it delete the registry key? Does it set another key to ignore certain registry keys?

Just overall curious on what "disabling" does in the task manager startup menu.

This only applies to windows 8 obviously as windows 7 uses Msconfig.

Comment: You should RegMon more, mon!

Comment: I can't really figure out what is going on. The registry key is untouched, but something else entirely is stopping that registry key when the computer is restarted? Any ideas?